# ItemSelected Event not Firing when "html:HtmlLabel(xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel)" is used instead of Label Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"ItemSelected="ListViewSample_OnItemSelected">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                <stacklayout>
                    <Label x:Name="Number" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    <html:HtmlLabel  x:Name="Text" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </stacklayout>
              </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

when we click on number label the "ListViewSample_OnItemSelected" is firing but when we click on Text label the event is not firing

Comment: try setting its InputTransparent property to true

Comment: Thanks @Jason.....It works

Answer (score 0):

Jason answer worked for me too:

```
<html:HtmlLabel  x:Name="Text" Text="{Binding Text}" InputTransparent="True"/>
```